# bad api request in vuejs with axios?

Tags: vue.js

I have a method to request a movie form an API. I have used axios to get my request with an await before the get and async before the method. I debugged it, and it is at the `const { data: results } = await axios.get(ui.movieName.baseUrl + ui.movieName.urlScoped)` line. Is my utilization of async and await is needed ? or I don;t use promises right way?

```
async loadMovieName () {
      const { data: movies } = await axios.get(baseUrl + urlMovie0)
      this.movieName = movies.movies[0].name
      }
```

Comment: The use of await here is correct

Comment: Have you checked what's happening in your browser developer tools? You can see if it's sending the request and what it gets back

Comment: Have you tried to put your request inside a try catch statement? For me, i never did an axios request without being in a try ctach. Also are you sure about your url is ok and have the right route to the api? Inside movies when you make the axios get, is movies.movies[0] is ok, it look sketchy imo. And last the ting i would think would be if get is the right method for your request.

Comment: Yep in the network tab. You can also try with Postman. Then, if it's working double check the actual state with your Vue devtools.

Comment: i was not searching in the right direction... only needed try catch and finally-_- feel a bit dumb...

Comment: Not sure how a try/catch is solving this. Indeed, it will not error out but you want it to work in the `try` anyway. You'll not gonna have any result (actual data) from the API in the `catch` block.

Comment: you are right.. i thought it was try catch, but it wasnt. when i added try catch as suggested.Tehn, i deleted the code above and wrote it again inside the try catch manually.from there, the code worked. after, i wanted to chek if your comment change something without try catch and.... the code also work? but it is the same code i started with!? maybe when i copied  "await axios.get(..." from pdf? dont know why in the first place it didnt work, but work now.

Comment: It could be some enconding problems maybe?

Comment: I didnt found a way to chek my pdf encoding, but from what i read, it depend on some factor, but it would be imposible that the encoding for a pdf file would be utf-8 like my ide. maybe it could be it.